# There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying

Tags: typescript, installation, nestjs, yarnpkg

I recently switched on EndeavourOS based on Archlinux, made all my installation without any problem and tried to create a new NestJs project after installing NVM and Node latest version with it and NestJs/cli with it.
After creating the new project, I selected npm first and the npm install never finished and crashed before. I find it weird and tried to create it with Yarn, here again it didn't finished.

I tried some solution that I have find on internet and none of them worked.
In my terminal I got 4 times `There appears to have trouble with your network connection. Retrying...` then `error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/ts-jest: aborted".`

I have actually try a lot of different solution like adding time for the timeout (up to 300000), clearing the cache by force, trying to install again the NestJs/client. I don't have any proxy setup, I have try to download it from ethernet cable, wi-fi and sharing connection from my phone, none of them worked.
Knowing that I'm connected to a wifi of a dormitory of a school.
I'm currently running out of solution so I don't really know what to do now.

- Node version -> 18.14.1
- Nest version -> 9.2.0
- NVM version -> 0.39.3
- Yarn version -> 1.22.19

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a same Issue like you. Are you living in Korea? Because if you living in Korea and using a KT internet Service, You could read this [link](https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/issues/3992).

I don't know the cause but if I use other internet service(like SKT, LG) it works fine.

Comment: I'm actually leaving in Korea and yes both my internet school/my mobile internet are from KT internet service. I'll try to find another network not under KT and try, thank you.

Comment: I used my VPN and it fixed the problem. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: It's good to hear you fix the problem. Your welcome

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is an issue with your school network. however, you can try to change the registry for yarn by using the following command in the terminal:
`yarn config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/`

Or using npm directly in your project folder by using: `npm init -y`